why does tokio::spawn require a Send bound for local variables
my test code:
use tokio::task::yield_now;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        let rc = Rc::new("hello");
        println!("{}", rc);

        yield_now().await;
    });
}

I don't understand，since a Tokio task runs on only one thread at a time, there won't be any data races involving the local variable rc across multiple threads. So why does tokio::spawn require a Send bound for local variables?
is compile failed:
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:6:5
    |
6   | /     tokio::spawn(async {
7   | |         let rc = Rc::new("hello");
8   | |         println!("{}", rc);
...   |
11  | |     });
    | |______^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `{async block@src/main.rs:6:18: 6:23}`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<&str>`, which is required by `{async block@src/main.rs:6:18: 6:23}: Send`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/main.rs:10:21
    |
7   |         let rc = Rc::new("hello");
    |             -- has type `Rc<&str>` which is not `Send`
...
10  |         yield_now().await;
    |                     ^^^^^ await occurs here, with `rc` maybe used later
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.39.2/src/task/spawn.rs:167:21
    |
165 |     pub fn spawn<F>(future: F) -> JoinHandle<F::Output>
    |            ----- required by a bound in this function
166 |     where
167 |         F: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error


You are correct. This is not necessary for soundness. It is just that the compiler is being overly strict.
tokio::spawn() requires the future to be Send, and future is not Send if it holds any non-Send value across .await points. But what we really need is another auto trait, not Send, let's call it SendNoEscape, that will be implemented for Rc (because if it does not escape from the future, it is sound to move it between threads), and not implemented for, say, MutexGuard (that really needs to stay on the same thread). Unfortunately, such trait does not exist, and it may never be.
Emphasis by @Cerberus: values captured by the async code (including async fn parameters) must still implement Send (as there can be copies on other threads); but values created in the async code can be SendNoEscape. The compiler can easily track that.
Edit: I was correctly pointed out on IRLO that I was missing one important detail - thread locals. Our async block can store the Rc in a thread local, move thread, other code in the original thread will access the thread locals, and dang! we got two Rc pointing at the same object within different threads. A similar exploit can be found with the async block accessing a thread local. Since we probably want thread locals to be sound, that means this API has to be unsound.

"it is sound to move it between threads" - nope. If we keep one clone of the Rc on one thread and move another clone of the same Rc (which is, on type level, indistinguishable from any other Rc) to another thread, we can have a data race over its counters. That's what Rc: !Send is preventing.

@Cerberus Except you cannot. Try to do that.

The correct answer to the question is that the code is sound, but there is no way for the compiler to know that it is. This answer implies that there exists a method together with a trait the compiler could reasonably use to detect that this code is safe, but I don't think that is reasonable. If I am wrong, please provide more detail.

@trueequalsfalse But the compiler could detect that, as I said, with an additional auto trait.

@trueequalsfalse To expand on this more: no async block/function is unsound just because it holds an Rc across .await, which means that we could have another auto trait implemented for Rc.

Then I assume this trait would be automatically implemented for all async block futures not cloning the Rc? The question is how the compiler knows what methods should be considered disallowed inside the async block for it to implement this trait. Would only Deref be allowed? Furthermore, if clone is not available, what would be the use of the Rc. The only use I can come up with is already covered by something like this. I also wonder how it would work for types other than Rc.

@trueequalsfalse Cloning the Rc is fine. You can hold multiple clones of it in the same async block, because they will all move to a new thread together.

"no async block/function is unsound just because it holds an Rc across .await" - but how is "holding across .await" different (in terms of thread-safety) from simply "moving into thread::spawn", except being possibly a move between threads and not a guaranteed one? And moving Rc into thread::spawn is unsound (again, that's why it is !Send).

@Cerberus The difference is that with thread::spawn(), you (the caller) may already hold clones of the Rc, and now you share them with other threads, which is unsound. But with async blocks, no other code can hold clones of the Rc, only this async block. That means that if this async block will move thread, all clones of this Rc will move to the same thread. This is essentially the same as OnlyOneCloneRc that can be moved between threads, except that here we have multiple clones, but we are guaranteed they are all moved together. Think about this hard and you'll realize that's true.

So you propose that values captured by async block and created by async block should be treated differently (with the former required to be Send and the latter required to be only SendNoEscape)?

@Cerberus Yes, indeed. But this is totally feasible for the compiler to implement.

@Cerberus I edited the answer to clarify that.

@Cerberus Actually, now that I think of it, the compiler cannot track that exactly: a value created in the async block can originate from values captured by the async block. So to be safe, the async block will have to be non-Send if there is any non-Send captured value, even if it is dropped before the first .await. This is not a breaking change, currently: the compiler doesn't track whether a value is dropped before the .await in any way other than blocks, and there is no way to block a capture...

@Cerberus ...However, there are plans to be more precise (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69663, but it doesn't cover everything). If they will happen, this will become a breaking change.

It seems like references behave like they implement this non-existing trait (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cacc0b78957283fa84fa14f3e78ab02b). Maybe this can be used as a work-around?

@trueequalsfalse You forgot an .await, that's why it works.
